# Annotation on PDF in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app i am using `UIWebView` for displaying the PDF. Now I need to annotate content. is there any way to do that without using [PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com/) ?

Comment: What you need to do for annotations ? You want inbuilt annotations ? Like if added, it will we viewable in any PDF Viewer ??

Answer (score 0):

I've made research a short time ago about annotations on PDF. My conclusion is that if you want a full compatibility it will be really hard to do it by yourself. PDF's specs are heavy, and there is no free libs for helping you, PSPDFKit is the simplest (but not the cheapest, you can look for other libs) way to win weeks of development.